# Phinx Class Not Found PHP

Tags: php, database, database-migration, slim-3, phinx

So I'm trying to set up Phinx a database migrations tool in Slim however, I'm having a little trouble getting the migration to work properly it keeps giving me this error `Fatal error: Class 'App\Database\Migrations\Migration' not found in C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\www\sites\hassanaljadooa\database\migrations\20170804115407_created_user_table.php on line 7` when ever I try to migrate.

I know it has to do with the Migrations class but I spell checked it multiple times I couldn't find any typos in class, and I'm quite frankly lost this error just shouldn't exist from my point of view.

To make life easy for anyone trying to help, here's the link to the bitbucket repo hosting my entire source code for this project https://hassanaljadooa@bitbucket.org/hassanaljadooa/hassanaljadooa.git just clone this repo and start looking.

The main files to look at are phinx.php in the root of the directory, app/database/migration.php, and the database/migrations folder.

side note:: im using psr-4 to load classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the relevant code into the question itself instead of a link. Links can go bad over time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the composer autoloader to phinx.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```